# Non-Clustered Index scan issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have a table on which I have created Non-Clustered Index, but in a query I am not able to make Table Seek on ipReq. As you can see in first image I have created index and also tried with different combinations. But didn't get success to make this table in seek. Due to this query my overall performance has been degraded. Let me know if anyone wants more information which I haven't added.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is something off about the query. The WHERE predicate has inv.BillNo = 'Billno' and at the same time the JOIN has  inv.BillNo = CONVERT(varchar, ipReq.RequestId). That means ipReq.RequestId must also be 'Billno'. Is this correct for your query? Also, why is a CONVERT required. I would suggest the following: Change the index to contain RequestId as the index key and IPNo as included column, and change the query to remove the CONVERT. If the CONVERT is still needed, please explain why.

Comment: We don't even know what table has the index since you have removed so much information. Are you table & column names really a secret?

Comment: @RnP: CONVERT is required as BillNo is in VARCHAR and RequestID is in BIGINT and this couldn't be changed. I have also tried your suggestion for changing in index for key column and included column but still its not working.

Comment: @James Z: There are 3 tables inv,ipReq, ipAdmi. ipReq table contains non clustered index and taking cost 77% and Index scan as you can see in image.Let me know if you want more clarity.

Comment: You're fetching from ipReq using `CONVERT(varchar, ipReq.RequestId)` -- so that index isn't really going to work. The cost is just an estimate, and can be totally off. You're also mixing outer and inner joins. If you can't change the datatype of RequestId. maybe creating a computed column with convert + index helps.

Comment: @JamesZ: I am agree with you regarding I have used CONVERT function, so My Index is not working. But is there any other way to handle this things and we could convert Index scan into seek!!!

Comment: Either change the datatype or try with an index computed column with the varchar version of the field. At least I can't figure out any other option for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168028/discussion-between-dhruv-and-james-z).

Comment: As per James Z and RnP's feedback I came to find that We should not use any functions in Where conditions to take advantage of Index Seek on table. Thanks James Z for clearing my query.